# Show specs texts with Jasmine 2, Protractor and Gulp

Tags: jasmine, gulp, protractor

I have a Gulp configuration file that runs Protractor/Jasmine like this:

```
.pipe($.protractor.protractor({ configFile: 'protractor.conf.js', args: args || ['--baseUrl', 'http://localhost:' + basePort] }))
```

But the report shown in the console are just dots, instead of the actual specs tests. How can I make Jasmine be verbose?

This was possible with the `isVerbose` option in Jasmine 1, but I can't find the equivalent for Jasmine 2.

Comment: i just searched ... stack overflow gulp ... on Google ... this answer was on first page of Google results - its only an hour old - woah!

Answer (score 3):

What we are doing is setting these jasmine settings:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
    print: function() {}  
}
```

And using [`jasmine-spec-reporter` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) that provides a nice and detailed test output:

```
onPrepare: function () {  
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');      
    // jasmine spec reporter
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        displayStacktrace: 'all',
        displayPendingSpec: true,
        displaySpecDuration: true
    }));
}
```

Comment: How to do that in a node environment (only), to run specs by using `npm test`? I have not found anything about using `--verbose` here ...